# Isn't it counterproductive to have systemd, upstart and init.d all running at the same time in a system?

Tags: upstart, systemd, init.d

I've been reading about the many different start up methods on boot by Ubuntu. And it's great that things are moving forward, but right now we have three different ways to start processes on boot, all running at once. Isn't this counterproductive? Wouldn't it be much faster and efficient if there was only systemd going forward?

I struggle to understand how this works on boot, if they all go at once, or one after the other, hence why I am asking.

Comment: I was under the impression that only one method was used. Upstart is still included as a fallback in the advanced screen of Grub.

Comment: If you look in `/etc` there is `/etc/init` used by upstart `/etc/init.d` used by vsystem and `/etc/systemd` used by systemd, so either systemd is backwards compatible or all of them are running at once. This is why I find it confusing.

Comment: If you needed to use upstart for some reason, then the system would still need it's files. Same with init.d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … so either systemd is backwards compatible or all of them are running at once. This is why I find it confusing.

The root of your confusion is that conclusion.  It's wrong.  The existence of directories in your filesystem does not imply that the subsystems associated with those directories *are running*.  In fact, they do not all run simultaneously.  One only has to see [the boot-time menu choice between upstart and systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Switching_init_systems) to understand that only one of these is active for any given run of the system.

Indeed, "init.d" isn't a subsystem.  It's a subdirectory.  The *subsystem* would be System 5 `rc`, a subsystem which hasn't been the default on Ubuntu Linux for nigh on a decade, at the time of writing this.  Both upstart and systemd can read System 5 `rc`'s files and symbolic links.  ([In systemd's case, for example, it translates those files and symbolic links on the fly, repeatedly, into its own native mechanisms.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132))  But that does not mean that System 5 `rc` is running when either upstart or systemd are.  It most definitely is not.

Your title question assuming those falsehoods as its premises is thus unanswerable.